# Pyomo: sending options="threads" to cbc solver causes an error

Tags: multithreading, pyomo, coin-or-cbc

It is possible to activate multithreading in a command line:

```
$cbc -threads=6
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver
Version: 2.9.9
Build Date: Aug 21 2017
```

```
$command line - cbc -threads=6 (default strategy 1)
threads was changed from 0 to 6
```

But when I try to activate this option in pyomo code

```
opt = SolverFactory('cbc')
result = opt.solve(instance, options="threads=4")
```

I get an error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 561, in solve
    self.options.update(kwds.pop('options', {}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyutilib/misc/misc.py", line 360, in update
    if type(d[k]) is dict:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The `options` keyword argument expects a dictionary. If you want to use the same syntax as the command line, you're after `options_string`

```py
opt.solve(instance, options_string="threads=4")
opt.solve(instance, options={"threads": 4})
```

Comment: Thank you! According to misc.py I guessed that this argument expects a dictionary. There is no more error, but only one thread is used, not 4. I use AbstractModel. Should I use only ConcreteModel to activate multithreading ?

Comment: @ElizavetaGolubeva ensure that the CBC executable is multi-thread compatible. If you compiled from source, you ought to have specified this as an option. Also, and as far as I know, multiple threads are only useful in the branch and bound phase of the solve.
PS: I have also written a solver wrapper for Pyomo to make selecting solvers and getting variables final results easily if you want to check it out: https://github.com/judejeh/PyomoSolverWrapper